# make onclick function not work until css animation finishes

Tags: javascript, css

I have these "previous" and "next" buttons that move some slides on my website.
When you click one, it goes to the next or previous slide and they animate using the css3 transition property, and changes the left property += or -= 800px of the sliding container.

```
#sliding-container {
position: relative;
left: -1600px;

transition: all 2s ease;
-moz-transition: all 2s ease;
-webkit-transition: all 2s ease;
-o-transition: all 2s ease;
}

.slide {
width: 800px; height: 500px;
background-color: white;

transition: all 2s ease;
-moz-transition: all 2s ease;
-webkit-transition: all 2s ease;
-o-transition: all 2s ease;
}
```

This is the js:_

```
    function slide(direction) {
            if (direction == 'prev') {
                    $("#sliding-container").css('left', '+=800px');

            }

            else if (direction == 'next') {
                    $("#sliding-container").css('left', '-=800px');

            }
        }
```

This slide function get called onclick:_

```
        <div class="fade" id="fade1" onclick="slide('prev')"><</div>
        <div class="fade" id="fade2" onclick="slide('next')">></div>
```

THE PROBLEM

But the problem is,if you click the next or previous button twice quickly, it messes up,that's why, I want the function to not run again on click until 2 seconds have passed(i.e, until the transition is done). How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a variable such as running to true when the button is clicked.  You'll then need to bind to the animation end like this:

OBJECT.bind('animationend webkitAnimationEnd ',function(e){
       running = false;
    });

That way you don't have to play around with delays or timeouts and can wait for it to tell you it's done.

Then on your click you can check if it's currently running or not before you decide to run the animation.

Comment: thanks, I'll try it but I need a bit more detail, could you just tell what the js line should exactly be, I don't really understand how to write that line of js you gave according to the situation.

Comment: Sure thing, so looking at your code you would probably want this:

$('#slide-container').bind('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd mozTransitionEnd',function(e){running = false;});

That will bind to any transition end of the sliding container, which is what you are transitioning, and when it finishes it will do what you want it to in that function.

Comment: I'm sorry but that didnt work, on the other hand, I did solve the problem and I'm posting it as an answer.. Thanks anyways, you did give me an idea as to how to use the timer.

Answer (score 0):

I used a timeout function, and with the help of Fernker, I thought up of how to use the timeout.

I added this before the in the head section,

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var running = false;
    </script>
```

I added this to the top of the slide function,

```
running = true;
```

and this line at the bottom of the slide function

```
window.setTimeout(function() {running = false;}, 2000);
```

2000 because, that's the time for the transition.

And I edited the onclick part

```
        <div class="fade" id="fade1" onclick="if (!running) { slide('prev'); }"><</div>
        <div class="fade" id="fade2" onclick="if (!running) { slide('next'); }">></div>
```

And now it works! So basically it's fernker's suggestion, just with a timeout, since the binding wasn't working.

Comment: I think my solution should work had you maybe kept tinkering with it.  While your way works it now will break if you change the transition time or the timeout time. This may not be an issue on such a small script but is bad practice overall if it can be avoided.